# "Sua conexão a este site não é particular"

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Desde ontem à noite, o site não força mais HTTPS e exibe esta mensagem. Há alguma coisa errada? Ou é este o comportamento normal?

PS: Testei digitando `https://` no endereço. Entra normalmente no SSL, mas acredito que o normal seria redirecionar pro SSL mesmo em cima de `http://`.

Comment: Talvez esteja relacionado com a [migração de toda a rede para https](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/)

Comment: Mas ao fazer login? É que nunca forçou o https a não ser no login.

Comment: Relacionado: [Metabot do chat com links para as perguntas em HTTPS](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5268/7210)

Comment: Ou é só no meta?

Comment: Os dois sites. Meta e SOpt.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez o site nunca forçou https, a não ser no login. Mas funciona https://pt.stackoverflow.com, e não funciona https://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Aqui o principal está acessando normalmente em https

Comment: Aqui dá erro no certificado SSL no META, testei no Chrome e Firefox, o site principal está Ok. Outro problema, se estou no site principal de qualquer site da rede e clico no "StackExchange button" para ir para o meta, sou direcionado para o META sem SSL (isto é um problema no link), mas se eu clicar para ir para qualquer outro site da rede eu continuo em SSL.